Scale bar in Azimuthal but not Robinson despite reprojected layer and matching project CRS - why?
I need a world map in World Robinson (ESRI:54030) projection (or Winkel Tripel, ESRI:54042), but the scale bar won't appear unless it's set to "Map Units". Since I need KM, this won't work. Weirdly, there's no problem with the scale bar if I create a map with Azimuthal instead (ESRI:54032).
I have checked that the project CRS matches the layer CRS and I've reprojected layers through the process tool instead of on the fly. I even reset my CRS defaults and restarted the whole thing from scratch, but every single time, using the same exact process, I get a scale bar with Azimuthal and I do not get one with Robinson or Winkel.
For the world map, I've used both the "world" typed into the coordinate bar on QGIS and the shp from Natural Earth. I'm using QGIS 3.36 on Windows.
What am I missing here?
